# Why is the sound of my notifications will always loop, it makes me a headache

Tags: android

The following code is not a problem , but I did not get the results you want：
【Please help me set】

NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
        mNotifyBuilder.setTicker("****: " + TimeUtil.timeLongToString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        mNotifyBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.wealoha.social/raw/dd"));

```
    if (mSessionMap.size() <= 0 && mSessionMap.size() <= 0) {
        mSessionMap.put(notification.sessionId, 1);
        mNoticeMap.put(notification.sessionId, 1);
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("content");
        mNotifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, DialogueActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(DialogueActivity.TAG, notification.sessionId);
        resultIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(DialogueActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        Notification noti = mNotifyBuilder.build();
        noti.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(mContext, MonitorNoticeColumnClearBroadcast.class);
        deleteIntent.setAction(GlobalConstants.AppConstact.MONITOR_NOTICE_COLUMN_CLEAR_BROADCAST);
        noti.deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, deleteIntent, 0);
        mNotificationManager.notify(mNoticeMap.get(notification.sessionId), noti);
```

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you execute this code? What do you mean with it "will always loop"?

Comment: What I mean is this: When the notification came,Tips for ringtones, will always ring,Until I went to touch the notification bar,Then it will stop.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer,Thank you very much Mike Laren,
I put it in a property to noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL，
This can be resolved，